# coding in one branch and splitting to many?

Tags: git

I coded several things in a single branch where about 5 other branches were merged.

Now, I want to split this in the other 5 branches.

Some of the changes for 3 branches were made in a single file like: FileA has changes A:1, A:2, A:3. Branch1 wants A:1, Branch2 ...

These 5 branches are all using the master as base.
This means none necessarily contains what the other 4 does, but may now contain new code that will be present in more than one.
Like a new function `GetSpecialTime()` that is needed in some branches and will be the same when all pull requests are merged.

I can't also checkout any of the 5 branches because it complains not being able to, as there are incompatible changes as:

```
File level merge required.

error: Entry
'the/happy/source/file.cpp' not uptodate. Cannot merge.

Staying on branch
'TheBloatedBranchScaringTheDeveloper'
```

I cant commit on the current bloated branch because this is a "local work branch", not a branch to commit directly, only after committing on the other 5 branches, I will change back to the bloated and merge the other 5 locally on it. This is the way I want my workflow.

Each branch belongs to a different pull request.
All PRs will be available at the same time.
Each PR may be accepted and merged at any time and in any order (of couse there may be required conflict resolve from the 2nd one on).

What is the best way to deal with that situation?
Any tool?
Scripts?
Never do that again? (nah... I will end doing it again for sure)

I use `git gui`.

Comment: What you did is unclear. You had a branch `feature` where you merged 5 other branches. Then what? Was there conflicts which you did not yet resolved? Could you explain what you did step by step and then what state you are left in?

Comment: no wait. I had a main branch, the master one. I created 5 branches based on master. I did changes to each of the 5 branches. I merged them all in a WorkAllInOneBranch (the bloated one). ----- now I did changes on that last branch and I need to split the changes on the other 5 branches. I cant resolve a conflict if I cant change to another branch because of the checkout error message I described. If you think I can clarify the question differently from what is there, could you specifically point where? unless this explanation suffices, then I can reword there if needed :)

Comment: If you successfully merged the 5 branches into `WorkAllInOneBranch` and then did some new work on top of that, why would you have any conflict? Also, what do you mean by "split the changes on the other 5 branches". Do you mean that in the new work that you would like to commit, some of the work would conceptually belong to different branches?

Comment: the best would be to provide a test case I guess? "why would you have any conflict?" the conflict is actually not being able to checkout the other branches to commit partial things there with the message "File level merge required.". By "split" I mean fileA has changes A1 and A2... Branch1 wants A1, Branch2 wants A2... Yes, the new work belong to diff branches because they belong to diff PullRequests. One day in the future, all PRs will be in the same branch, merged together, but for now, I need to create 5 PRs, and they may be accepted independently of each other. Thx, I improvedquestion :)

Answer (score 0):

> the best would be to provide a test case I guess? "why would you have
>   any conflict?" the conflict is actually not being able to checkout the
>   other branches to commit partial things there with the message "File
>   level merge required.". By "split" I mean fileA has changes A1 and
>   A2... Branch1 wants A1, Branch2 wants A2…

You can't switch branch because you have working directory changes. The solution would be to commit your work into several commits (you can stage specific lines) which will then be cherry-picked to the respective branch in which they should have been committed.

The `WorkAllInOneBranch` can then be discarded for now or reset to a common base (e.g. `master`) for the re-integration of the work.

Comment: "you can stage specific lines" :o, I have to try that!

Answer (score -1):

The short answer would be indeed 'never do that again'.
But since you found yourself in this situation already now you can checkout each one of the 5 branches you want bring the changes to and cherry-pick the commits from the branch you worked on.

So let's say this is what your branch with all the work looks like:

```
a58c7b8 (HEAD -> feature) commit we want to copy
f4ac9ea Fix spelling mistakes
9ebb329 Add some functions
4f7f95e Edit Readme
9750037 initial commit
```

You can checkout the branch where you want to bring the changes to and cherry-pick the commit(s) you need:

```
git checkout <targetBranch>
git cherry-pick a58c7b8
```

Comment: yup, I forgot to mention not being able to checkout sry.

Comment: Looks like you have some uncommited changes on your current branch.
Either commit them or in case they are  not completed yet stash them (git stash) so that you are able to checkout the branch you want.

Comment: interesting. btw, I cant commit on the current branch because this is a work branch (and not a branch to commit directly, only after commiting on other branches and merging locally on it). I will check the `git stash` thx!

Comment: I think `git stash` could work, but I need to create patches to partially apply each of them on the 5 branches, I wonder if `git stash` would help on that, only tests can tell..